# Executable is in current directory but can't be run

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I'm having a weird problem where I have an executable in a directory, but when I try to run it, bash says that it doesn't exist:

```
kiarashsadr@pandoras-box:~/Downloads/Tether/linux$ ls
adb  run.sh

kiarashsadr@pandoras-box:~/Downloads/Tether/linux$ ls -l
total 1204
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kiarashsadr kiarashsadr 1226659 Mar  9  2013 adb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kiarashsadr kiarashsadr     521 Oct 29  2012 run.sh

kiarashsadr@pandoras-box:~/Downloads/Tether/linux$ ./adb
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

output from `file`:

```
kiarashsadr@pandoras-box:~/Downloads/Tether/linux$ file adb
adb: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

wut??

Comment: Show `ls -l` output.  Maybe there's a funny character in the name?b Maybe show the first 3 lines or so of the file — if there's a shebang line and that's malformed, you can get that because the command interpreter can't be found.

Comment: Your `adb` is a 1.2 MiB script?  Or an executable program?  Scripts are text files.  That looks like it is probably an executable.  And if so, what do you get from `file ./adb /bin/sh`?  Are they the same type?

Comment: adb is an executable (binary) file. what do you mean by the first 3 lines?

Comment: right, it's an executable. I mistakenly said script.

Comment: I seem to recall that this error pops up when the loader can't find a dynamic lib which the executable references. Is that possible?

Comment: Looking at the first three lines of an executable is not a good idea; cancel that — but I was misled by the wording in the question.  What does `file` have to say?

Comment: @Peter: I imagine bash is just calling `perror("bash: ./adb")` and doesn't differentiate between "the executable is missing" and "I can't find libc (or whatever)."

Comment: This question's answers http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run show how to get a list of referenced libraries.

Comment: ldd says that it's "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: One could also call [`explain_execve_or_die(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_execve_or_die), which should either work or produce a more useful error message.  Naturally, this requires a C compiler and might not be portable (is libexplain POSIX standard?).

Comment: Are you trying to run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system?

Comment: ^ that's what I was just about to say is probably the case...

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752727/executing-32-bit-code-under-ubundu-64-bit-installation-error-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer. I'm currently reading http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system. Bash doesn't differentiate between this case and "no such file or directory" case.

More about this topic: [Executing 32 bit code under Ubundu 64 bit installation error- No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752727/executing-32-bit-code-under-ubundu-64-bit-installation-error-no-such-file-or-di)

More on how to run 32-bit executables on 64-bit systems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

Comment: I can confirm the error you get in that case is exactly 'no such file or directory', as if the file wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by VOR73X, **the reason in this case is that the file is a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit architecture**. You *can* run it, but you need a compatibility layer to do so. If you have it:

```
mintaka:/home/lserni # file ansi
ansi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
mintaka:/home/lserni # uname -a
Linux mintaka 4.0.1-1-default #1 SMP Wed Apr 29 15:04:53 UTC 2015 (e3a374a) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mintaka:/home/lserni # ./ansi
Syntax: ansi [file|-]
```

...and otherwise you get 'no such file or directory'.

However, there might be other reasons to be unable to run a file that "seems" to be there (or even *is*).

Missing dynamic libraries would give a distinctive error (at least they do on my system, Linux OpenSuSE 13.2):

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

## Another possibility...

...is that the file is not named as you think it is. The file you asked for is *really* not there!

For example (using the same obsolete file as before)

```
mintaka:/home/lserni # mv ansi 'ansi '
mintaka:/home/lserni # ls -la ansi*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14268 Sep 17 23:29 ansi
```

The file seems to be there **but its name now ends with a space**, so as you would expect...

```
mintaka:/home/lserni # ./ansi
bash: ./ansi: No such file or directory
```

Of course if the file is called correctly, escaping the space...

```
mintaka:/home/lserni # ./ansi\
Syntax: ansi [file|-]
mintaka:/home/lserni #
```

Other tricks are possible (I did it to myself once by mistake and have seen some worm using this trick to hide from a casual 'ls'). For example UTF8 invisible characters.

Try

```
ls -la | hexdump -C
```

to verify that the name is indeed what it ought to be.